About Yo-yo motion and forces constraint
The purpose of the Euler-Lagrange equation, is supposed to enable us to describe a system with the fewest possible coordinates, using generalized coordinates instead of traditional ones.
However, in many references and videos, I don't see that the number of Euler-Lagrange equations equals the number of generalized coordinates.
A simple example can be seen in a certain reference http://www.dzre.com/alex/P442/lectures/lec_30.pdf , or the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkfm6niYQWY , where we have a single independent coordinate ($y$ or $\phi$) for yo-yo motion, that is sufficient to study the system. Yet, two equations of motion are derived.
Doesn't this contradict the the purpose of the Lagrangian formulation, or am I missing something?
Best regards.

In the video you linked, they're using the Lagrange equation of first type, i.e. Lagrangian equations where the method of Lagrangian multipliers is used to prescribe a constraint. This way you get 3 equations (2 for the kinematic variables, and 1 for the Lagrange multiplier - usually something related to the force needed for the constraint to be satisfied). L.eqns of the II kind need that you find first the relation $y(\theta)$ linking the 2 kinematic variables through the constraint

Following this latter approach, you get one dynamical equation for one generalized coordinate, and then you can evaluate all the other kinematic variables from kinematic relations, and dynamic variables like forces or moments usually from equations of motion of some components of the mechanical system

@basics
Thank you so much.
